# How to embed a new string in url?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, url-rewriting, permalinks

I am creating a custom tours and travel theme in which I have created custom post type Cities, Locations, Destinations and i am using custom permalink structure. `/%category%/%postname%/`

So now I want to append a state name or district name before that city, destination or location name. Let me make it more clear by giving you an example .

The current url structure is like this.
http://test.com/custom_post_type_slug/post_name_slug

And how I want it to be like this.
http://test.com/Custom_dynamic_string/custom_post_type_slug/post_name_slug
Right now i am doing something like this

```
function add_places_rewrite_tags(){
add_rewrite_tag('%district%','([^/]+)');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_places_rewrite_tags' );

add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
add_rewrite_rule(
    "/([^/]+)/hotel/([^/]+)/?",
    'index.php?post_type=hotel&district=$matches[1]&p=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_query_vars' );
}
function custom_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
   $query_vars[] = 'district';
   return $query_vars;
}
```

but it's still not giving me the desired results 
and i am also using a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) to analyze the re-wright rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
add_filter( 'query_vars','my_insert_query_vars' );
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )

{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['(.+?)/custom_post_type_slug/(.+?)/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=custom_post_type_slug&dynamic_string=$matches[1]&custom_post_type_slug=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}

function my_insert_query_vars( $vars )
{
    array_push($vars, 'dynamic_string');
    return $vars;
}
```

Comment: Thanks deepa. I am doing it something like this I have this url abc.com/hotel/new_view but i want to insert a new string which will be its district which is saved in its meta-field so the url will become something like this abc.com/shimla/hotel/new_view

Answer (score 0):

After adding this to functions.php and customizing it toward your needs, be sure to visit Settings > Permalinks in the admin to flush the rewrites.

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
function custom_rewrite_rules()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        "/([^/]*)/custom_post_type_slug/([^/]*)/?",
        'index.php?post_type=custom_post_type_slug&Custom_dynamic_string=$matches[1]&custom_post_type_slug=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );

    /**
     * Add the above to Query Vars
     */
    add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_query_vars' );
}

function custom_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'Custom_dynamic_string';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Then, in your templates, you can get the "Custom_dynamic_string" (or whatever you decide to call it) variable using this function:

```
$custom_dynamic_string = get_query_var('Custom_dynamic_string');
```

Comment: Thanks jake.
I am doing it something like this
I have this url http://abc.com/hotel/new_view but i want to insert a new string which will be its district which is saved in its meta-field so the url will become something like this http://abc.com/shimla/hotel/new_view

Comment: You should be able to use the above code to do that. And then when you link to it, you would have to build your links manually: $url = site_url() .'/'. $meta_value .'/'. $post->post_type .'/'. $post->post_name .'/'; And on the page you could get the meta_value to filter things and check against the stored meta value...